# зачем используется os.path.abspath(__file__)) вместо просто __file__

Tags: python, django

В django путь определяется как,

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Переменная `__file__` содержит полный путь к модулю.
Зачем от нее брать os.path.abspath.
Почему не использовать просто,

```py
os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: Судя по этому ответу https://stackoverflow.com/a/7116925, утверждение `Переменная __file__ содержит полный путь к модулю` верно не всегда (или не всегда в одном смысле верно)

Comment: `__file__` может содержать относительный путь, например `'../../main.py'`, что не человеко-читаемо, поэтому приводится к абсолютному пути

Comment: @anl, а вот это, кажется, надо в ответы.

Answer (score 2):

`__file__` - это путь к файлу, из которого загружен модуль.

Соответственно, если не пользоваться данной конструкцией, то при обращении из разных каталогов, он будет принимать разные значения.

И он не всегда содержит абсолютный путь к файлу.

Использование `__file__` в сочетании с различными модулями `os.path` позволяет всем путям относиться к местоположению каталога текущего модуля. Это позволяет переносить ваши модули / проекты на другие компьютеры.

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести пример, когда __file__ содержит разные пути. Я вот просматриваю __file__ как из запускаемого модуля, так и из импортируемого. Всегда вижу абсолютный путь

Comment: Единственное смущает, что из вызываемого модуля в __file__ = 'D:\\project/manage.py',  а из импортируемых __file__ = 'D:\\project\\webdev\\urls.py' То есть нет прямого слэша... Почему так?

Comment: Как уже ответили ниже, если мы вызываем `__file__` из текущего модуля, то dirname вернёт пустую строку. Для этого используется такая конструкция.

Comment: А пути различаются, потому что через прямой слеш обозначается непосредственно путь к файлу из данного модуля. А при импорте возвращается директория файла(которая разделяется двумя обратными слэшами).

Answer (score 2):

[Начиная с версии 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html), `__file__` содержит абсолютный путь всегда кроме одного случая: когда скрипт вызван напрямую (`__name__ == '__main__'`). Т.е. если есть файл с таким содержимым

```
def f():
    print(__file__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f()
```

при его запуске скрипт выведет лишь имя файла, т.е. относительный путь. Если же функцию `f` откуда-то импортировать, то `__file__`, выводимый в функии `f`, будет содержать уже абсолютный путь. По-видимому, во избежание подобноый путаницы используется конструкция, про которую Вы спрашиваете.

**P.S.** Как я понимаю, это обновление - следствие замены `''` в `sys.path` на `os.getcwd()`.